# Убрать подсказки типов Rust-Analyzer при переносе строки в VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, visual-studio-extensions

Мне удалось отключить подсказки при присвоении значений и в параметрах функций.
Однако я не могу понять, как убрать подсказки при переносе строки.

Может ли кто-то подсказать, как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За это отвечает параметр `rust-analyzer.inlayHints.chainingHints`.

Для себя я также отключил `rust-analyzer.inlayHints.parameterHints` и `rust-analyzer.inlayHints.typeHints`.